# how to check sql_trace in oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle

I am newbie in Oracle database.
I want to ask how to check sql_trace of oracle system? 
I made mistake run these command
`ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = true`
without checking the status first. 
I already googling but can not find how to check the `sql_trace` status true or not. 
I have two similar database, so I want to check status on the other database and set it same status in another database.

Comment: Try `SELECT sid,serial#,module,service_name,sql_trace
 FROM v$session
 WHERE username='SCOTT'`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I check and I can view the status of sql_trace. The status was disabled. However it become a doubt. When I run again "ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = true" and check the status. It still disable. My alter SQL was wrong? Or I need run commit to make my sql work? Thank you very much

Comment: @saka1029: your query shows the setting of individual sessions, which can be changed by `ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace=TRUE`.

Comment: @wolφi Sorry, I misread SYSTEM as SESSION.

Comment: I see. So it for check session. Not for check system right? *because I try change v$session become v$system and not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the current system wide setting of `SQL_TRACE`, use

```
SELECT name, display_value, isdefault, ismodified 
  FROM v$parameter WHERE NAME='sql_trace';
sql_trace   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
```

If you switch it on, it changes to `TRUE`:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = TRUE;
sql_trace   TRUE    TRUE    SYSTEM_MOD
```

And back again:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = FALSE;
sql_trace   FALSE   TRUE    SYSTEM_MOD
```

A warning, though: `SQL_TRACE` was already [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams243.htm) in version 11.2. `DBMS_MONITOR` and `DBMS_SESSION` should be used instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That was really helpful. There is any way to make ISMODIFIED part become FALSE again? So it can back to first setting sql_trace   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE

Comment: The documentation of [`V$PARAMETER`] says to `ISMODIFIED`: *Indicates whether the parameter has been modified after instance startup.* I would guess therefore that it is back to `FALSE`once you restart the database.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.  But restart database seems impossible, I will leave it like current condition.